# Conditionally Change String Name

Tags: sql-server

I have a large data source that's automatically uploaded in a SQL Server Table so I am unable to manually change the data. Every now and then there are records that are mislabeled. 98% of the dataset contains unique Patient_fins; however, for patients that have been to both locations (ED and EDU), Patient_fin are duplicated, which is fine.  For example,

```
  Patient_fin    CHECKIN_DATE_TIME       TRACKING_GROUP
    1           2018-01-01 01:37:00          EDU
    1           2018-01-01 04:37:00          ED
```

I'm running into issues when the patients tracking group is not correctly labeled (both labels are the same when the CHECKIN_DATE_TIMEs are different) . For example, I can tell from the CHECKIN_DATE_TIME that the patient has been to two different locations ED and EDU, yet the tracking group is the same. The second row for Patient_fin 1, tracking group should read 'ED'

```
   Patient_fin CHECKIN_DATE_TIME       TRACKING_GROUP
      1           2018-01-01 01:37:00          EDU
      1           2018-01-01 04:37:00          EDU
```

For instances where the TRACKING GROUP is incorrect, is there a way in SQL where I can recode the record with the later CHECKIN_DATE_TIME so the TRACKING_GROUP reads ED. A priori knowledge tells me the later CHECKIN_DATE_TIME will always be associated with ED and not EDU.

Comment: Will the checkin dates always be on the same day where you want to change the second tracking group value? Or do the dates not matter, only if there are two of the same Patient_fin?

Comment: Are there scenarios where there could be more than 2 of the same patient_fin?

Comment: Seems a rather contrived bit of logic but not that difficult. The easiest solution would be to use a cte to return the order using ROW_NUMBER. Then simply update the cte where RowNum = 2. But what about row 3 or 33?

Comment: All great questions. There could be occurrences when the first checkin date is 10PM and the second checking date 1am so yes, for the same patient fin, the checkin dates could fall on two different days. In this case, I would still want to change the second record Tracking_Group to ED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF only there will ever be two records with the same Patient_fin and you don't need to account for the first record being ED, what happens then? You would then be left with two records having a TRACKING_GROUP = ED:

```
--This will do pretty much what Sean Lange described except instead of a cte, it uses
--A subquery to get the records with a row number, partitioned by the Patient_fin
--It then joins this on the table by Patient_fin and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME and updates the second record for a Patient_fin
UPDATE dbo.SomTable
SET TRACKING_GROUP = 'ED'
FROM dbo.SomeTable AS st
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Patient_fin, CHECKIN_DATE_TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Patient_fin ORDER BY Patient_fin) AS [RowNumer]
    FROM dbo.SomeTable
) AS x
ON x.CHECKIN_DATE_TIME = st.CHECKIN_DATE_TIME AND x.Patient_fin = st.Patient_fin
WHERE x.RowNum = 2
```

Comment: This works. The bonus of a cte is that you don't have to query the table twice. You simple update the cte. But regardless +1 from me.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you. I appreciate it and thank you for the constructive criticism, I see why you chose a CTE over a subquery. If you add your CTE version I will kindly upvote.

Comment: I don't care about the points. You get the idea of how it works. :D

Comment: @SeanLange Ok. Well I appreciate your insight, I didn't even think about it that way until you explained it, I can at least up vote your comments. :)